# VM can access internet despite iptables DROP rules

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iptables, ping, tcpip

I have installed VirtualBox and I have 2 Ubuntu VMs running on VirtualBox. Please see the network diagram:
[image: network diagram]

VM 1 (Client VM) has static IP address of 10.0.2.2. Gateway VM has 2 IP addresses - 10.0.2.1 and 10.0.1.5. DHCP is disabled on the 10.0.2.0/24 network. Please see the following diagram:

[image: diagram]

I don't understand how the Client VM is able to ping the gateway VM despite the fact that all the traffic is blocked on the Gateway VM. Both the 10.0.2.0/24 and 10.0.1.0/24 networks are "NAT Network" in VirtualBox 6.1

Comment: If it's the "NAT Network" mode, are you sure you're actually pinging the other VM and not the VirtualBox internal router? Does the MAC address shown by `ip neigh` of the first VM correspond to the other VM?

Comment: Guess: It somehow goes over the loopback interface - VirtualBox [NAT Networks](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat) are a bit odd, and allow to get at the host loopback. Try "Internal Networking" between the VM1 and VM2 instead. You'll need static addresses, or an explicit DHCP server (which would usually sit on the Gateway VM).

Comment: One critical thing, IPTABLES has an order of operation meaning if your drop rule has an allow rule before it the **1st matching rule wins**.  You may have to move the drop rule higher in your iptables order.